Create a custom module with joomla 4 and ajax
I tried to created a simple module in joomla. I need it to record a number in a database, in ajax and inscrease aotomatically the next number to record.
I think there is a kind of confusion in my code and I looked a lot of forums and documentation, but I don't manage to find a solution.
Can you have a look in my code please and give me a piece of advice :
this is the mod_enregister_numero.php part. It creates an error 500. When I try to put the functions in a helper.php file, it doesn't work better.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Import des classes nécessaires
use Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController;
use Joomla\CMS\MVC\Model\BaseDatabaseModel;
use ModEnregistrerNumeroHelper\Helper;


$moduleclass_sfx = htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));

require_once JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_enregistrer_numero', 'helper');

class ModEnregistrerNumeroHelper extends BaseController
{
  
    public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = array())
    {
        // Récupération des paramètres du module
        $titre = $this->params->get('titre');
        $texteBouton = $this->params->get('texte_bouton');

        // Récupération du numéro suivant
        $numeroSuivant = ModEnregistrerNumeroHelper::getNumeroSuivant();

        // Affichage du module
        require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_enregistrer_numero', $this->params->get('layout', 'default'));
    }

    public function enregistrerNumero()
    {
        // Récupération des données POST
        $numero = Factory::getApplication()->input->get('numero', '', 'INT');
        $userId = Factory::getUser()->id;
        $dateEnregistrement = Factory::getDate()->toSql();
        $statutEnregistrement = 1;

        // Création d'un nouveau modèle
        $model = new BaseDatabaseModel;

        // Préparation de la requête SQL
        $query = $model->getDbo()->getQuery(true)
            ->insert($model->getTable('numeros'))
            ->columns(array('numero', 'user_id', 'date_enregistrement', 'statut_enregistrement'))
            ->values(array($numero, $userId, $dateEnregistrement, $statutEnregistrement));

        // Exécution de la requête
        $model->getDbo()->setQuery($query)->execute();

        // Envoi d'une réponse JSON
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true));

        // Arrêt de l'exécution du script
        Factory::getApplication()->close();
    }

    public static function getNumeroSuivant()
    {
        // Récupération du dernier numéro enregistré
        $db = Factory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('MAX(numero)')
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__numeros'));
        $dernierNumero = $db->setQuery($query)->loadResult();

        // Incrémentation du dernier numéro
        $numeroSuivant = $dernierNumero + 1;

        // Retour du numéro suivant
        return $numeroSuivant;
    }
}

and this is the default
.php part
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Récupération des paramètres du module
$titre = $params->get('titre');
$texteBouton = $params->get('texte_bouton');

// Récupération du numéro suivant
$numeroSuivant = ModEnregistrerNumeroHelper::getNumeroSuivant();

?>
<div class="mod-enregistrer-numero">
    <h1><?php echo $titre; ?></h1>
    <p>Numéro suivant : <?php echo $numeroSuivant; ?></p>
    <form id="form-enregistrer-numero">
        <input type="hidden" id="numero" name="numero" value="<?php echo $numeroSuivant; ?>">
        <button type="submit"><?php echo $texteBouton; ?></button>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form-enregistrer-numero').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Récupération du numéro saisi par l'utilisateur
            var numero = $('#numero').val();

            // Création d'une requête AJAX
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Configuration de la requête
            xhr.open('POST', 'index.php?option=com_ajax&module=mod_enregistrer_numero&task=enregistrerNumero', true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            // Envoi de la requête
            xhr.send('numero=' + numero);

            // Gestion de la réponse
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                    // La requête a réussi
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                    if (response.success) {
                        // Le numéro a été enregistré avec succès
                        alert('Le numéro a été enregistré avec succès.');
                    } else {
                        // Une erreur s'est produite
                        alert('Une erreur s\'est produite. Veuillez réessayer.');
                    }
                }
            };
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>

Can you help me please ?
I try the code.
I try to follow these link
https://www.techfry.com/joomla/how-to-create-joomla-4-x-module
https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Creating_a_Simple_Module
but it does not treat about he ajax call and helper.php.
And as my english is the enough strogn, I'm lost.
I just want to module work and allow me to record numbers in the database with ajax. I use Joomla 4.4.3
Thanks a lot
